# MongoDB Jmeter with SSL File

Tags: mongodb, jmeter

So I'm following the guide over on BlazeMeter about how to load test MongoDB with Jmeter here
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/

In my case I do have a connection string because our Mongo Deployment is using a replicaset.  No biggie I just hardcoded it into the MongoClient section as I was having issues with passing it through as a variable.

But here is the deal.  Our Mongo servers use a SSL file as a part of the authentication mechanism.

Is there a way I can just plug the SSL into a variable inside of jmeter and then have it be set properly in the database connection portion of the load test?

````
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;

try {

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("MY_CONNECTION_STRING");

    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));

    vars.putObject("collection", collection);

    return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MongoDB Driver  Reference  Connecting  SSL](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/ssl/)

> **JVM system properties**
>
> A typical application will need to set several JVM system properties to ensure that the client is able to validate the SSL certificate presented by the server:
>
> `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`: the path to a trust store containing the certificate of the signing authority
>
> `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`: the password to access this trust store

The aforementioned properties can be defined either in [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) or passed to JMeter startup script via [-D command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Also make sure to have `?ssl=true` directive in your `MY_CONNECTION_STRING` JMeter Variable

Comment: thank you for you help with this.  Turns out I don't need to have the ssl=true for this particular string.  But I am still facing an issue with my connection not sure what the issue is but it just will not connect.